# Multiple PHP mysqli prepared statements (INSERT UPDATE SELECT) weird behavior

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a problem using following PHP function:

```
function saveCommentOnDB($arg_textComment, $arg_score, $arg_userEmail)
{
    $result_tmp = null;

    $this->conn->autocommit(false);

    echo "saving\n";
    echo "text comment: \n";    
    var_dump($arg_textComment); // OKAY
    echo "comment score: \n";
    var_dump($arg_score);       // OKAY
    echo "user mail: \n";
    var_dump($arg_userEmail);   // OKAY

    try {

        //[tag1] $query_1 = "INSERT INTO commenti (userFirstname, userEmail, textComment, score, feedback) VALUES ( (SELECT firstname FROM utente u WHERE u.userEmail = 'asd@asd.asd') ,'asd@asd.asd', 'This is an example comment.', 5, 0);";
        $query_1 = "INSERT INTO commenti (userFirstname, userEmail, textComment, score, feedback) VALUES ( (SELECT firstname FROM utente u WHERE u.userEmail = ?) ,?,?, ?, 0);";
        $query_2 = "UPDATE utente SET commentID=(SELECT c.commentID FROM commenti c WHERE c.userEmail = ?) WHERE userEmail = ?;";
        $query_3 = "SELECT commentID, textComment FROM commenti WHERE userEmail = ?;";

        $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare($query_1);
        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare($query_2);
        $stmt3 = $this->conn->prepare($query_3);

        $stmt1->bind_param("sssd", $arg_userEmail, $arg_userEmail, $arg_textComment, $arg_score);
        $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $arg_userEmail, $arg_userEmail);
        $stmt3->bind_param("s", $arg_userEmail);

        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt3->execute();

        $stmt3->bind_result($col1, $col2);
        $stmt3->fetch();

        echo "result:\n";
        var_dump($col1);    // OKAY
        var_dump($col2);    // OKAY

        $result_tmp = array(
            'commentID' => $col1,
            'textComment' => $col2
        );

        $this->conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
    }

    return $result_tmp;
}
```

Please, ignore the `echo` and `var_dump`, I put them only for debugging.

The problem is that in this function these three prepared statement seems to work not correctly. In particular the statement `$stmt1`: the result of `$stmt3` is correct (as if `$stmt1` and `$stmt2` are executed correctly), but I don't see anything on my Database. In other words: the statements works correctly 'temporarily' during the execution, but in MyPHP Admin there's nothing on the table `commenti`.

For example, we assume having this on the DB:

[image]

Now I launch the function with following parameters:

- `$arg_textComment = 'This is an example comment'`
- `$arg_score = '5'`
- `$arg_userEmail = 'asd@asd.asd'`

and we have on my browser console:

[image]

ie: the commentID (28) is right and the comment text (*commentcomment*) was "saved", then I recheck the DB but I have still this:

[image]

and `var_dump($stmt1)` after the execution is:

```
stmt1:
object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(41)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["param_count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["id"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

The `var_dump` seems to be ok, but DB nope.

So I try to execute the query 'manually' by this (it will be executed only the code into the green lined box):

[image]

and I have what I expected:

```
sql> INSERT INTO commenti (userFirstname, userEmail, textComment, score, feedback) VALUES ( (SELECT firstname FROM utente u WHERE u.userEmail = 'asd@asd.asd') ,'asd@asd.asd', 'commentcomment', '5', 0) [2017-01-21 17:38:28] 1 row affected in 11ms
```

[image]

Keep in mind `score` value is store on DB as `float`.

The SQL query of the `$stmt1` is the same I inserted manually (`INSERT INTO...` via PHPStorm).

Why the first doesn't works and instead the second yes?

Hope this screencast may help:

https://youtu.be/UsYK93jYVqA

Comment: if your first query doesn't work then there was an error during its execution

Comment: I tried to comment `$stmt2` and `$stmt3`, the `$stmt1` works perfectly and I can see the new row on the DB. I tried also to coalesce the three statements into one, but this not helped. Have no idea.

Comment: Still, the answer is always the same: if some data is not in the DB, then some query failed. If some query failed then there was an error. If there was an error you have to read it and fix the issue. As simple as that

Comment: Using `$stmt->execute()` solved the problem. All queries were correct.

Comment: wat? there is no $stmt variable in the code

Comment: @YourCommonSense as you can see: I tried to report all details. There were no errors and since there are no errors, what I should read? :(

Comment: I had abbreviated `$stmt` as not to repeat `$stmt1`, `$stmt2` and `$stmt3`.

Comment: Never in my life I've seen such inconsistent course of actions

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, change from this:

```
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt3->execute();
```

to this:

```
        $stmt1->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
        $stmt2->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
        $stmt3->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
```

Have no idea of why...  but it works after many tests.

Comment: your "solution" makes absolutely no sense